# How do I attach camera to Spark.components.VideoDisplay

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, mxml, flex-spark

I'm using Flash Builder and created a spark-application Flex project that will stream video from the local camera. If I use `mx.controls.VideoDisplay`; there is no problem since it has `attachCamera(camera)` method. But Spark's `VideoDisplay` component does not have that method. I know I can use mx controls inside a Spark app but I want to know:

- What is the real difference between `spark.components.VideoDisplay` and `mx.controls.VideoDisplay`?
- How do I attach camera to `spark.components.VideoDisplay`?
- Is there any advantages if I go with spark (since it's newer to mx library)?

thanks.

**EDIT**: In the documentation this is mentioned: "*Starting with Flex 4.0, Adobe recommends that you use the spark.components.VideoPlayer  class as an alternative to this class. (mx.controls.VideoDisplay)*"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here are the specifics to get this working:

```
import mx.events.FlexEvent;

import org.osmf.net.StreamType;

import spark.components.mediaClasses.DynamicStreamingVideoItem;
import spark.components.mediaClasses.DynamicStreamingVideoSource;

private var _cam:DynamicStreamingVideoSource =  new DynamicStreamingVideoSource();
private var _dynVideoSource:DynamicStreamingVideoSource;

protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{

    _dynVideoSource=new DynamicStreamingVideoSource();

    var videoItems:Vector.<DynamicStreamingVideoItem>;
    videoItems=new Vector.<DynamicStreamingVideoItem>();
    videoItems[0]=new DynamicStreamingVideoItem();

    _dynVideoSource.host= "";
    _dynVideoSource.streamType=StreamType.LIVE;
    _dynVideoSource.streamItems=videoItems;

    mycam.source=_dynVideoSource;

    var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera(); //Camera.names[0]);
    cam.setMode(640, 480, 15);
    cam.setQuality(0, 80);
    mycam.videoObject.attachCamera(cam); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful code. To remove the camera simply do this: cam.videoObject.visible = false; cam.source = null;

Comment: mycam is spark VideoDisplay.

Answer (score 4):

Straight up, the answer is that you can't attach a camera to the Spark `VideoDisplay`. Sorry. I was trying to make this happen too, but I had to default to the mx `VideoDisplay` and there's nothing wrong with using it :)

Spark is newer and I prefer to use it whenever possible too, but in this case, you just need to use the MX control. It happens.

Comment: The correct answer should be the one by Tony instead.

There's no need to use the mx namespace when the spark videoDisplay component does actually support this.

The slight difference is that you should be attaching with videoDisplay.videoObject.attachCamera() instead of videoDisplay.attachCamera().

Comment: When this was written, this was the correct answer. They only recently added this functionality to the SDK.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to attach the camera to `videoDisplay.videoObject` - but the videoObject was always null, which throws an error.

To resolve that I created a dummy DynamicStreamingVideoObject and passed it as the source

```
_cam = new DynamicStreamingVideoSource();

<s:VideoDisplay id="mycam" source="_cam" />
```

then, in the creationComplete handler of the application i did this

```
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
mycam.videoObject.attachCamera(cam);
```

this resolved the issue.

Comment: should be source="{_cam}"
but anyway this does not solve the problem: 
mycam.videoObject is still NULL

Answer (score 2):

Been looking for a solution to this and found the below

```
var cam:Camera = Camera.getCamera(); 
cam.setMode(320, 240, 15);
cam.setQuality(0, 0);
var myCam:Video = new Video(320,240);
myCam.attachCamera(cam);
myVideo.addChild(myCam);
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shorter workaround:

```
<s:VideoDisplay id="camVideoDisplay"
                source="dummy"
                autoPlay="false"
                autoDisplayFirstFrame="false"/>
```

In this case, the Video object can be then referenced as `camVideoDisplay.videoObject`, e.g.:

```
camVideoDisplay.videoObject.attachCamera( .. );
```