# Attach Camera with Flash Builder 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, web-applications, camera, flash-builder

I just want to start my webcam to display video, for this I wrote this code but it is not working. Any idea why It must not be working ? What possibly I might be making mistake ?

Please here is the code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.controls.Alert;

            protected function video_d_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                var camera:Camera = Camera.getCamera();
                if (camera) {
                    video_d.videoObject.attachCamera(camera);
                } else {
                    Alert.show("You don't seem to have a camera.");
                }
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
    <s:VideoDisplay x="15" y="23" id="video_d" creationComplete="video_d_creationCompleteHandler(event)" />
</s:Application>
```

Instead I see the popup with an error:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at vv/video_d_creationCompleteHandler()[C:\Users\Malik\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\vv\src\vv.mxml:15]
    at vv/__video_d_creationComplete()[C:\Users\Malik\Adobe Flash Builder 4.6\vv\src\vv.mxml:26]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.core::UIComponent/dispatchEvent()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:13152]
    at mx.core::UIComponent/set initialized()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:1818]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:842]
    at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1180]

Awaiting your answers with many thanks.
Thanks
Bilal Ahmad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `VideoDisplay.videoObject` is `null`. AFAIK it can be fixed like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4767042/645918). If you don't like this approach it's possible to do something like this:

```
<s:VideoDisplay  x="15" y="23" id="video_d" creationComplete="video_d_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <s:source>
        <s:DynamicStreamingVideoSource host="" streamType="{StreamType.LIVE}">
            <s:DynamicStreamingVideoItem  />
        </s:DynamicStreamingVideoSource>
    </s:source>
</s:VideoDisplay>
```

Or use good old `mx:VideoDisplay`.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't tried your code yet... but the link was helpful.